# Writing to row using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to write a list to a row in Python using openpyxl, but to no avail.

The list contains say for example ten values. I need to open an existing worksheet, and write those ten values to their own cell, along one row.

I need to use openpyxl due to its functionality of overwriting existing worksheets compared to xlsxwriter where you can only create new worksheets.

Comment: The sample code in the documentation covers this: `ws.append()`. Please explain why your code is different.

Comment: Because it only "Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet." and I want to specify which row to start at.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't say that. You can only add empty rows if necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/), scroll down to the heading **Writing Values to Cells**.

TLDR:

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
>>> sheet = wb['Sheet']
>>> sheet['A1'] = 'Hello world!'
>>> sheet['A1'].value
'Hello world!
```

or if you prefer

```
sheet.cell(row=2, column=3).value = 'hello world'
```

Update: changed to wb['Sheet'] syntax as per @charlieclark comment, thx

Update: To write mylist into row 2

```
for col, val in enumerate(mylist, start=1):
    sheet.cell(row=2, column=col).value = val
```

Comment: `get_sheet_by_name()` has been deprecated. Use simply `wb['Sheet')` instead.

Comment: Thanks but this only writes to individual cells and doesn't write to entire row of cells.

Comment: Updated my answer. If it helps, please remember to accept it.

Comment: Very annoying that there doesn't seem to be a simple way to write a row. It's just _wrong_ to copy parts of a spreadsheet by reading rows then separating them into individual cells to write them back into rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'bird']
ws.append(mylist)
wb.save('myFile.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I made a function for you. I have it in a "openpyxlutils" file on my computer.
It allows you to put either the starting row letter or number (but the letter can't be like AA or BB).

```
def write_row(write_sheet, row_num: int, starting_column: str or int, write_values: list):
    if isinstance(starting_column, str):
        starting_column = ord(starting_column.lower()) - 96
    for i, value in enumerate(write_values):
        write_sheet.cell(row_num, starting_column + i, value)
```

Comment: I ended up taking out lines 2 and 3 and just going with starting column number instead of supporting letter characters.

Comment: This is outdated - use ws.append()