# How do you save dictionary data to the matching excel row but different column using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read a column (A) from an excel spreadsheet.  I then iterate through a dictionary to find the matching information and then I want to write this data back to column (C) of the same Excel spreadsheet.

I have tried to figure out how to append data back to the corresponding row but without luck.

**CODE**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

my_dict = {
    'Agriculture': 'ET_SS_Agriculture',
    'Dance': 'ET_FA_Dance',
    'Music': 'ET_FA_Music'
}


wb = load_workbook("/Users/administrator/Downloads/Book2.xlsx")  # Work Book
ws = wb['Sheet1']  # Work Sheet
column = ws['A']  # Column
write_column = ws['C']


column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for l in column_list:
        if k in l:
            print(f'The dict for {l} is {v}')
            # append v to row of cell index of column_list
```

So, if my excel spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Without the appended data]

I would like Column C to look like this after I have matched the data dictionary.

[image: Final data entry]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this with your method you need the index (ie: row) to assign the values to column C, you can get this with `enumerate` when running over your `column_list`

```
    for i, l in enumerate(column_list):
        if k in l:
            print(f'The dict for {l} is {v}')
            # append v to row of cell index of column_list
            write_column[i].value = v
```

After writing all the values you will need to run

```
wb.save("/Users/administrator/Downloads/Book2.xlsx")
```

To save your changes

That said, you do a lot of unnecessary iterations of the data in the spreadsheet, and also make things a little bit difficult for yourself by dealing with this data in columns rather than rows. You already have your dict with the values in column A, so you can just do direct lookups using `split`.

You are adding to each row, so it makes sense to loop over rows instead, in my opinion.

```
my_dict = {
    'Agriculture': 'ET_SS_Agriculture',
    'Dance': 'ET_FA_Dance',
    'Music': 'ET_FA_Music'
}


wb = load_workbook("/Users/administrator/Downloads/Book2.xlsx")  # Work Book
ws = wb['Sheet1']  # Work Sheet

for row in ws:
    try:
        # row[0] = column A
        v = my_dict[row[0].value.split("-")[0]] # get the value from the dict using column A
    except KeyError:
        # leave rows which aren't in my_dict alone
        continue

    # row[2] = column C
    row[2].value = v

wb.save("/Users/administrator/Downloads/Book2.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth answer.  This does make sense to clean up my processing.  The only think I don't know and I am researching now is why it is not writing those results `row[2].value` back to the spreadsheet.  Nothing is updated on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Using another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920108/writing-to-row-using-openpyxl, I tried writing to the cell with the hardcode `ws.cell(row=2, column=3).value = 'hello world'`, but this didn't work either.

Comment: I have tried multiple methods to write to a spreadsheet.  Could this be a Mac issue?  I have tried using this method as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395058/how-to-write-to-a-new-cell-in-python-using-openpyxl#:~:text=import%20openpyxl%0Awb%20%3D%20load_workbook(filename%3D%27xxxx.xlsx%27)%0Aws%20%3D%20wb.worksheets%5B0%5D%0Aws%5B%27A1%27%5D%20%3D%201%0Aws.cell(row%3D2%2C%20column%3D2).value%20%3D%202

Comment: Did you run wb.save()?